# Unable to connect MySQL Workbench through SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm fairly new to using MySQL Workbench. I should also mention that I host my database in shared hosting.

I was able to connect to my databases using Standard TCP/IP connection, but I would like something more secure.

So I tried setting up the Require SSL setting for Standard TCP/IP, but even though the site supports https, I receive an error:

[image]

I've also tried to set up connection over SSH tunnel using the following settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAAXr.png but it also fails:

[image]

The SSH connection should work, as I am able to connect to the hosting using PuTTY.

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "even though the site supports https". This has nothing to do with HTTPs, or HTTP in any form. SSL, maybe, but not HTTP. Anyway, "access denied" suggests you could connect, but your user details are invalid. I would guess perhaps you need to match the username with the remote host, or the "all hosts" wildcard. in MySQL, users are restricted by the hostnames which you specify they can connect from.

Comment: @ADyson I have tried both SSH user/pass with PuTTY and database user/pass with Workbench (over standard connection) and both work

Comment: So? Is your MySQL user configured to be able to connect from 127.0.0.1, or not?

Comment: @ADyson I was finally able to connect. The issue is I needed to use "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1".Would connecting through SSH tunnel even if SSL is not enabled be secure? or would the info travel through the Internet in plain text? Thanks!

Comment: SSH is always encrypted ("Secure Shell"!!), and that's entirely unrelated to whether SSL is enabled on a direct TCP/IP connection (which is also entirely unrelated to whether SSL is enabled on the HTTP connection to the website). They are all different protocols with different configurations.